# Download file from provided URL in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am new. I am trying to write a code in Android Studio - a program to download file using provided URL link. Please help! Thanks!!!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: please provide a detailed, specified question for your problem. E.g how to download file on android from an provided url?

Answer (score 1):

To start with , you can look into AsyncTask. Refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Do check the following :

1. user has an internet connection available
2. Make sure you have the right permissions (INTERNET and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE); also ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE if you want to check internet availability.
3. Make sure the directory were you are going to download files exist and has write permissions.
4. Use AsyncTask to download file.

For downloading file refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog).Its pretty detailed.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate your help! Will look into these info. Regards!